# How to make content draw behind a non full width Toolbar (Like new Gmail or Google App)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

What I'm trying to implement is a Toolbar that is not full width (has a margin on all sides of 16dp) like the following:

Gmail - Please note that the `RecyclerView` can be seen scrolling behind the toolbar [image: Gmail]

Google App - Same thing, the cards can be seen behind the toolbar.
[image: Google App]

Additionally, these toolbars hide when scrolling down and appear when scrolling up.

*The content of the toolbar is not what I'm worried about right now.*

I'm assuming this is done using a Coordinator Layout so this is the skeleton I have:

- Coordinator Layout

  - AppBarLayout

    - Toolbar
  - NestedScrollView (appbar_scrolling_view_behavior)

    - ConstraintLayout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".MainContentFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        ...
```

This is the output before scrolling
[image: output]

And after scrolling down
[image: output2]

As you can see the space outside the toolbar is not transparent but has that grey background, since the content is going under it and cannot be seen.

Answer (score 0):

**The idea behind showing the content behind the toolbar:**

1. Setting a negative margin to the scrolling view (`NestedScrollView`/`RecyclerView`) which equals to what you want the size of the blank area when all the content are scrolled up (all the stuff below the toolbar, nothing behind); it's assumed **-100dp** in the below demo
2. Reverse back this negative margin on the child of the `NestedScrollView` (in layout), or the 1st child of the `RecyclerView` (programmatically)
3. Put the scrolling view on top of the `AppBarLayout` so that the background of the `AppBarLayout` don't obscure the scrolling content to let them appear in the back of the toolbar.

**Cosmetics:**

- Remove the elevation of the `AppBarLayout` to 0 to make it as not existing; just the ToolBar is there.
- Set the background color of the `AppBarLayout` to transparent, so now it takes the background of the root layout.

Demo:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:text="@string/longText" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For the `RecyclerView`, you can't control its children with layouts, so reversing the margin can either by

- Having 2 layouts one with the 100dp top margin  for the first child, another without margins for the rest children. And decide which layout in the adapter's `onCreateViewHolder()`
- Adding the margin in adapter's `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    if (position == 0) {
        Resources resources = holder.itemView.getContext().getResources();
        float dip = 100f;
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                dip,
                resources.getDisplayMetrics()
        );
        params.topMargin = (int) px;
    } else
        params.topMargin = 0;

    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
    
    //...... rest of code
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should just wrap all widgets inside `CoordinatorLayout` with `FrameLayout` and change `AppBarLayout` position to the end:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".MainContentFragment">

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        ...


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```